# Infinite sequence of $\sqrt{2^n}$ equals $i$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I am no mathematician, in fact I consider myself not very good at math at all, however I do enjoy it. Anyways, I was messing around when I remembered a numberphile video I watched a while back about solving the infinite sequence 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 etc.

I thought, "can I apply this to the powers of two?" So, I set up an infinite sequence of the powers of two:

$$s = \{1 + 2 + 4 + 8...\}$$

When you multiply it by two...

$$2s = \{2 + 4 + 8 + 16...\}$$

Well, then you could say...

$$2s = s - 1$$

$$s = -1$$

Now I thought this was interesting, so I expanded on it:

$$\sqrt{s} = \sqrt{-1}$$

or

$$\{\sqrt{1} + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{4}...\} = i$$

or

$$\{\sqrt{2^0} + \sqrt{2^1} + \sqrt{2^2}...\} = i$$

This I thought was especially interesting, so I tried to convert it to an equation:

${\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}} \sqrt{2^n} = i$
(I apologize for the bad LaTeX by the way)

Anyway, all I want to know is whether I got this right or not, and if I didn't then I'd like to know why.

Comment: In general, $\sqrt{a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n} \neq \sqrt{a_1} + \ldots + \sqrt{a_n}$ amongst other things.

Comment: There is a degree of validity in the $s=-1$ (Ramanujan did some weird stuff) but I'm afraid square roots don't distribute over sums.

Comment: u should be careful when summing two series.. clearly $s=\infty$ and so it cannot be equal to $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first claim that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n = -1$ is incorrect, but interesting and I'll discuss it below.

In your second claim, you make the error $\sqrt{a+b} = \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$. This is incorrect for the same reason $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$ is incorrect (instead $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$).

---

You used:

$S = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots$

$xS = x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots$

$S - xS = 1$

$(1-x)S = 1$

$S = \frac{1}{1-x}$

To get

$\sum x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$

and you applied this for $x = 2$ to get $\sum 2^n = -1$.

This sum *diverges* for $|x| \geq 1$, which is to say, if you add up the numbers, they don't get closer and closer to anything. For $|x| < 1$, they do get closer and closer, as you can see explicitly with $1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + \ldots$.

---

Plugging in $2$ for $x$ in the above formula is a type of *analytic continuation*. You found a formula that worked for some values of $x$, and tried it for values of $x$ that don't make sense in your original sum (because the sum diverges).

There are interesting reasons to perform analytic continuation, and a long history of it.

But the sum doesn't actually equal $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

We should be very careful about our series convergence.

The series you have defined is $s=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n=\infty$

And so, $s-1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n=\infty $.

So the thing which u got as $s=-1$ is wrong.
Here itself answer is over.

**Extra**

In the further steps u have used $\sqrt s=\sqrt{\sum 2^n}= \sqrt 1+\sqrt 2+\sqrt {2^2}+\ldots$ which is not true.